# 1D Heat Equation with different materials

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-conductivity, heat-conduction

I'm trying to solve a 1D-Heat Equation with Finite Difference Method in python.

The object I'm trying to depict has "Material A" with a high conductivity on the outside and a core of "Material B" with a small conductivity on the inside. I assigned the materials and their conductivity to the relative nodes with the help of an array.

After many steps, I would expect the resulting graph to show a dip in temperature where the "Material B" lies. The resulting graph shows a linear line though.

[image: Resulting Graph]

Is the heat equation applicable to different conductivities, or is my method flawed?

Heat Equation:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} T(x,t) - a \frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} T(x,t) = f(x,t).$$

FDM 1:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}T = \frac{T_{n,k+1} - T_{n,k}}{\Delta t}.$$

FDM 2:
$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}T = \frac{T_{n+1,k} - 2 \cdot T_{n,k} - T_{n-1,k}}{\Delta x^2}.$$

Added together and solved for T(k+1):
$$T_{n,k+1} = m(T_{n+1,k} - 2 \cdot T_{n,k} + T_{n-1,k}) + T_{n,k} + \Delta t \cdot f_{n,k}.$$

EDIT 2:

I think my problem does not lie in solving a heat equation, but rather coming up with the correct formulation of the Boundary conditions. I tried to depict what I want to model in the graphic below.

[image]

My goal is to simulate the shown case in python with the help of the FDE Method.

So far my Boundary conditions where:

$$u(x_0, t) = 100 ~~ \text{and} ~~ u(x_3, t) = 20 $$

also $$ u(x,0) = 20$$

Within the program, I used these BC's and the homogenous heat equation in an FDM approach:

$$T_{n,k+1} = m(T_{n+1,k} - 2 \cdot T_{n,k} + T_{n-1,k}) + T_{n,k}$$

I thought that, if $k(x)$ just using:

$$ k(x) = k_1 ~~~for~~~ x_0 < x < x_1 ~~~and ~~~x_2 < x < x_3 $$ and
$$ k(x) = k_2~~~ for~~~ x_1 < x < x_2 $$

I would have a realistic representation of my problem.

I tried to transfer Gert's question to mine but am not sure. If  I understand correctly, I have to include two additional Boundary conditions. One for each interface at $x_1$ and $x_2$.
I would then have to calculate 3 separate heat equations. One that depicts $x_0 ~~ to ~~ x_1$ and so forth.

Would that be a correct approach to solve my problem?

Comment: Tell us more about your finite difference setup.

Comment: The Heat equation is valid, even if $\alpha=f(\vec{r})$ ($\vec{r}$ is the position vector), i.e. strongly anisotropic materials. Are you looking for the transient solution or the steady state solution?

Comment: Hello Gert, I'm looking for a transient solution. Although I think that the steady state solution should also not show a linear line. Am I correct in that assumption?

Comment: I iterate the following equation: T[1:-1] = (T[1:-1] + sigma[1:-1] * (T[2:] - 2.0 * T[1:-1] + T[:-2])). Sigma is an array that contains the diffusivity of the materials. It looks like : [A,A,...,B,B,B,..,A,A,..]

Comment: Let’s see the PDE you solved.

Comment: Sorry I don't exactly know what you mean. Applying FDM to the heat equation gives me the equation I posted above. I will edit how I "solved" it in the post above.

Comment: *Am I correct in that assumption?* It depends wehther your Fourier PDE is homogeneous or not. If $F(x,t)=0$ then the PDE reduces to a second order ODE and $\alpha$ drops out to: $T''(x)=0$, which solves to a line, for simple boundary conditions.

Comment: So do I understand correctly: It does not matter how many materials are defined, there will always be a straight line as shown in my post above?

Comment: Your PDE is not valid for a material whose thermal conductivity varies with spatial position.  It’s OK away from the interface between the two materials, but not across the interface.  For a material whose conductivity varies with spatial position, the k has to be included within the outer spatial partial derivative.

Comment: No, it depends on the *boundary conditions* of your PDE. For 'simple' (e.g. homogeneous) BCs you'll get a straight line, irrespective of $\alpha(x,t)$. So no matter how many layers, the line is independent of $\alpha$. But if the BCs are time dependent it becomes more complicated.

Comment: Incidentally, your graph doesn't show $t$ and you don't specify $f(x,t)$. Your problem is posed incompletely...

Comment: Also, Chet Miller solved a problem like yours in one of my questions: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/286001/heating-transient-of-a-composite-rod Chet and me are the 'resident Heat equation nutters'. ;-)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answers so far. I looked through your question and tried to apply it to my problem. I posted an edit in which I hope to illustrate my problem further.